# Thread waiting for asynchronous callback

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a `Thread`, call it `WorkerThread`, whose job it is to make a given object, `SomeObject`, do some work periodically.

`SomeObject` is concerned with doing some communications through a socket. Some of the work it has to do is performed on a further thread dedicated to the socket I/O. Call that `CommsThread`. I consider `CommsThread` to be an implementation internal to `SomeObject`.

While `SomeObject` is busy doing its work, the idea is that `WorkerThread` would `wait()` on a monitor Object. When the asynchronous callback happens from `SomeObject`, `notify()` would be called within the callback handler and `Thread A` would then continue on its merry way.

This previously worked -- but only because `Object A` happened to be performing its asynchronous callback within the context of `CommsThread`, meaning that `notify()` could be called on the monitor object, allowing `WorkerThread` to wake and continue.

I have been refactoring things a bit, and realised that I think it's pretty poor design for my classes to call back asynchronously on a Thread other than that on which they were instantiated, or for those callbacks to happen on an "internal" Thread. The callbacks were previously happening in the context of `CommsThread`. Therefore within `SomeObject` I have used the Android `Handler` to cause the asynchronous callbacks to happen on the thread on which `SomeObject` was instantiated. This, I believe, is better design. But this now causes a deadlock situation concerning `WorkerThread`. Of course `WorkerThread` now sits in `wait()` indefinitely.

This brings me to two related questions:

- If I'm designing a class or interface which has asynchronous callbacks, is it convention or just generally A Good Thing for the callbacks to happen either on the thread the object was created on, or on the UI thread?
- Assuming I do design my classes according to the above and the asynchronous callbacks do not happen on a separate thread, how should `WorkerThread` effectively wait for such a callback? One workaround that comes to mind is to instantiate `SomeObject` on the UI thread prior to creation of `WorkerThread` and then pass it into the Thread. The asynchronous callbacks would happen within the context of the UI thread, so `wait()`/`notify()` will work.

Answer (score 0):

A third solution is to completely abandon the use of the archaic `wait/notify` mechanism and use a real concurrent structure.

I would suggest you study your requirements carefully and consider using a `BlockingQueue` for inter-thread communication or perhaps some careful `Lock` usage.

If you could expand on your actual requirements rather than assuming that a callback is the right approach I am sure we can help more.

The current attitude on callbacks is that they are almost always a smell. However, there are some patterns that look a lot like callbacks that are considered acceptable.

Comment: Many thanks. This is for an Android application where various commands (which are command-response sequences) are performed via a Bluetooth or USB connection. The way I have designed my command objects is such that a given type of command may be constructed, handed off to my 'command executor' which fires the command's payload via the connection, collects the response, and then calls back an asynchronous handler. I *think* this fits in quite well with the Android way of doing things and because some of my various state machines are event driven, but I'm always open to other ideas. (Cont...)

Comment: Having done some further research I note that an Android convention seems to be for callbacks to happen on the UI thread. If I do that, that would be one solution. Another approach I could do is make more use of the Android Looper and Handler classes. When I get more time tomorrow I'll try to expand on my question with some more concrete information about what I'm doing as I'd value any direction.